# Got stuck at trying to figure out what the single shot at inference for Variational Autoencoder should be

Tags: machine-learning, monte-carlo, neural-networks, bayesian-network

Let's say you have an already trained Variational Autoencoder where the parameters are $\phi, \theta$ for the recognition and generative models respectively. Let's also assume you have the following Gaussian factorization scheme:
$
\newcommand{\Norm}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\pz}{p(z)}
\newcommand{\ptheta}{p_{\theta}}
\newcommand{\encoding}{q_{\phi}(z \g x)}
\newcommand{\decoding}{p_{\theta}(x \g z)}
\newcommand{\g}{\,|\,}
\newcommand{\qphi}{q_{\phi}}
\newcommand{\qphizgivenx}[2]{\qphi(#1 \g #2)}
$
$$
\begin{split}
\pz &= \Norm(0,I)\\
\decoding &= \Norm(\mu_{\theta}(z),\sigma^2I) \\
\encoding &=\Norm(\mu_{\phi}(x),diag(\sigma^2_{\phi}(x)))
\end{split}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d,z \in \mathbb{R}^r, d>>r$, and $\mu_\phi, \sigma^2_\phi$ functions are neural network encoders while $\mu_{\theta}$ is a neural network decoder.

Now, according to [Kingma & Welling 2019 p. 30](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02691.pdf) $\log \ptheta(x)$ can be approximated by a Monte Carlo sampling procedure with $L$ iterations:
$$
\log \ptheta(x) \approx \log \frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{\ptheta(x,z^{(l)})}{\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}}    
$$

Here, $z^{(l)}$ are sampled from $\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}$. This operation is too costly for me so I want to do this in one shot. My question is, what would be the best $z^{(l)}$ to do this? Approximate answers are fine as long as there is some sound backing to it.

I tried a shot at this and here I am:

$$
\begin{split}
\log \ptheta(x) & \approx \log \sum_{l=1}^{L} \exp\{\log\ptheta(x,z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}\} - \log L \\
& \leq \max_{l \in \{1\dots L\}}\{\log\ptheta(x,z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}\} +\log L - \log L \\
& = \max_{l \in \{1\dots L\}}\{\log\ptheta(x,z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}\} \\
& \leq \lim_{L\to\infty}\max_{l \in \{1\dots L\}}\{\log\ptheta(x,z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}\} \\
& = \max_{z^{(l)}\in \mathbb{R}^r}\log\ptheta(x,z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x} \\
& = \max_{z^{(l)}\in \mathbb{R}^r}\log\ptheta(x\g z^{(l)})+ \log p(z^{(l)}) - \log\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}
\end{split}
$$

The above follows from the definition of LogSumExp and the final step is basically the factorization of joint distribution. I get an upper bound this way, my hunch is that this will be maximized at $z^{(l)} = \mu_\phi(x)$ and I numerically demonstrated this over a few examples by getting large $L$ samples. I believe it's due to the fact that $d>>r$ and we rather zeroize $\qphizgivenx{z^{(l)}}{x}$ by doing so but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is highly appreciated!